# tcp/ip socket receiver decode type

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, octave, decode

I have use socket TCP/IP to receive a bit stream of an FPGA board in Octave and Python.

In Octave, with
`[data_tcp1,len_tcp]=recv(client_tcp, 70848, MSG_WAITALL);`

I received the data with dimension **70848** with datatype is **uint8**

Now In python, I would have the same behavior like Octave, so I tried:

```
data_tcp1 = client_tcp.recv(70848)# data in byte
```

I got the same size: 70848 but with < class byte >. There is a lot of option in python that I have tried to get the same result like Octave.

```
data_tcp1 = client_tcp.recv(70848).decode('ISO-8859-1')
```

or,

```
data = client_tcp.recv(70848).decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```

or,
data = client_tcp.recv(70848).decode()

Is there any explication in this command? What is the option should I use to obtain the same behavior like in Octave?

Thanks with best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.decode` method of `bytes` instance is used for getting `str` (string) based on that `bytes` instance. If you wish to turn each byte into number you might use `list`, consider following simple example

```
data = b"\x00\x0F\xFF"
values = list(data)
print(values)  # [0, 15, 255]
```